# R code for looping through regression models, starting from Stata code

Tags: r, loops, regression, stata

New R user here, coming from Stata. Most of my work consists of running several regression models with different combinations of dependent and independent variables and storing the results. For this, I make extensive use of macros and loops, which to my understanding are not preferred in R.

Using the "mtcars" dataset as an example, and assuming I'm interested in using `mpg`, `disp` and `wt` as dependent variables, `hp` and `car`b as independent variables and adjusting all models for `vs`, `am` and `gear`, in Stata I would do something like this:

```
local depvars mpg disp wt // create list of dependent variables
local indepvars hp carb // create list of independent variables
local confounders vs am gear // create list of control variables

foreach depvar of local depvars {
    foreach indepvar of local indepvars {
        reg `depvar' `indepvar' `confounders'
        estimates store `depvar'_`indepvar'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it in R? Potentially using the tidyverse approach which I'm starting to get familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make R to follow your Stata code:

```
depvars <- c('mpg', 'disp', 'wt')
indepvars <- c('hp', 'carb') 
confounders <- c('vs', 'am', 'gear')

for (i in seq(length(depvars))) {
    for (j in seq(length(indepvars))) {
       my_model <- lm(as.formula(paste(depvars[i], "~", paste(c(indepvars[j], confounders), collapse = "+"))), data = mtcars)
       assign(paste0(depvars[i], "_", indepvars[j]), my_model) 
   }    
}
```

or with shorter code:

````
for (i in seq_along(depvars)) {
    for (j in seq_along(indepvars)) {
       assign(paste0(depvars[i], "_", indepvars[j]), lm(as.formula(paste(depvars[i], "~", paste(c(indepvars[j], confounders), collapse = "+"))), data = mtcars)) 
   }    
}```
````

Comment: Thanks, it works. May I ask you why your code also creates a "my_model" object which is identical to one of the stored results (in this case, "wt_carb")?

Comment: It’s just a temporary object to keep the code more readable. I didn’t bother removing it. You can also use one line within the loops to avoid this: 
assign(paste0(depvars[i], "_", indepvars[j]), lm(as.formula(paste(depvars[i], "~", paste(c(indepvars[j], confounders), collapse = "+"))))